# Using jquery highchart with dynamic php values fetched from mysql datatable

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

I tried finding a well explained example or at least a definition, but had no luck.
So basically I have a data-table, I want to fetch some values from it and display it using jquery high-chart.
So far, I have this:

```
<?php
include("connect.php"); //script for connecting to database and defining the $connection
$query = "SELECT * FROM meetings";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
$numberOfMeetings = 25; //this is mocked here so you can better understand the code
echo '<table>
      <tbody>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['memberName'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . ($row['timesPresent'] / $numberOfMeetings) * 100 . '%</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

I get a nice simple table with a lot of rows and 2 columns. First column is showing the name of the member and the second one is showing the percentage how many times he has been present on a meeting.

My question is now that I have this data-table and those values (I can always put the values in arrays if needed) how can I display it like this done on the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uDrQq/3/

I somehow need to pass the categories and the data from php values to the jquery code,but how?

Comment: Have you even looked at the highchart documentation ? There are plenty of example of how to create a chart. What can you not reproduce from the jsfiddle you link to ?

Comment: As an FYI, there is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: @Lepidosteus: Yes...I've been looking at the documentation, but it's not well explained how to pass those values to jquery. Maybe some help? Have you been working with it?

Comment: @War10ck: Yeah I know...thanks though. This code I wrote is all from the head, because I wanted to keep it as simple as it gets, so you can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    To use this you have to pass DB values from PHP to Javascript
    use php on same page or get the values from AJAX
    here is the demo how to use on same page

    <?php
    include("connect.php"); //script for connecting to database and defining the $connection
    $query = "SELECT * FROM meetings";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    $numberOfMeetings = 25; //this is mocked here so you can better understand the code

    $membername=array();
    $timepresent=array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $membername[]=$row['memberName']; 
        $timepresent[]=($row['timesPresent'] / $numberOfMeetings) * 100;
    }

    $membername="'".implode("','", $membername)."'";
    $timepresent=implode(",", $timepresent);

    ?>


//pass values in Javascript

$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Percentage of members on meetings'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [<?php echo $membername?>],
                title: {
                    text: "Members"
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Percentage',
                    align: 'middle'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2,
            valueSuffix: ' %'
        },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Present: ',
                data: [<?php echo $timepresent?>]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Are you sure this is gonna work though? It is possible to pass values from php to javascript like this?

Comment: yes,  i have use this code in one of my project..please make sure that string in format : 'membername1','membername2',...

Comment: if u are passing array use this .<?php echo join($data1, ',') ?>..it will give comma separated string

Comment: Well, half way there it seems. The join($data1, ',') doesn't work, but passing it as a string with
$membername="'".implode("','", $membername)."'";
does the trick for the vertical axis. So, the names are displayed, but the times in the horizontal axis are not. Therefore I don't get the animation or anything. Any other suggestions? :/

Comment: Oooooh! :))) The categories NEED to be passed to javascript as a string, but the data in series NEED to be passed to javascript as an array using join($data1, ','). Thank you SO much for all your help! It works now :)

Comment: Just repair your code like I said so other people will know :)